# how to hide the empty href value button with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a problem with jquery code when I try to hide a button that has no value in the href attribute, how to fix it correctly?
my code :

```
<a id="tw" href=""> Twitter</a>
<a id="fb" href="http://m.facebook.com"> Facebook</a>

<script>
$('#tw').each(function() {
    if($('#tw').attr('href') === '') {
        $(this).parents('#tw').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$('a').each(function () { if ($(this).attr('href') === '') $(this).hide(); });`

Comment: just a FYI it doesn't make sense to have a loop on the id `tw` since ids are supposed to be unique, there really should only ever be 1 of them. Consider using a class with a similar name and loop on the matches for that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select all the links `a` and check the `href` attribute, you're selecting just one ( the `#tw` )

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  if (!$(this).attr('href')) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="tw" href=""> Twitter</a>
<a id="fb" href="http://m.facebook.com"> Facebook</a>
```

Better yet, use css selector to get the links with empty `href` and hide them :

```js
$('a[href=""]').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="tw" href=""> Twitter</a>
<a id="fb" href="http://m.facebook.com"> Facebook</a>
<a id="other" href=""> Another link</a>
```

Or just css :

```css
a[href=""]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="tw" href=""> Twitter</a>
<a id="fb" href="http://m.facebook.com"> Facebook</a>
<a id="other" href=""> Another link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tw').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('href') != '') {
        $(this).parents('#tw').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers